# Elasticsearch query result with analysis of other documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to have a query result for example for "Michael J" which scores higher for "Michael Jackson" because in my documents "Michael Jackson" can be very often?

Answer (score 0):

The soultion is top programm a subquery in your favorite programming language. An example can be found here:

http://www.sebastianviereck.de/en/elasticsearch-subquery-scoring-optimization/